# How to migrate from SQLite database to Room about "String" field?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room, android-jetpack

I am trying to migrate a database from SQLite to Room in Android.

**But I got an error:**

> Migration didn't properly handle:
>   staff_message(db.entity.StaffMessage).
>        Expected:
>       TableInfo{message=Column{name='message', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
>   defaultValue='null'}}
>        Found:
>       TableInfo{message=Column{name='message', type='String', affinity='1', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
>   defaultValue='null'}}

Origin table was written like:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS staff_message( " +
                    "message String NOT NULL");");
```

And new table scheme is like:

```
@Entity(tableName = "staff_message")
data class StaffMessage(
        @ColumnInfo(name = "message") val message: String
)
```

The only difference is the type.

> String VS. TEXT

How can I migrate this table to the Room?

Comment: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/understanding-migrations-with-room-f01e04b07929 reading this will help.

Comment: oh... I should have done the migration by my self... Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is no data type in `SQLite` like `String`. You have to use `TEXT`

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS staff_message( " + "message TEXT NOT NULL");");
```

Comment: the table can be created with "String" field, too. And I already have the table created with "String" field. Now, my problem is I couldn't migrate my db to Room. (Now, I found the solution)

Answer (score 0):

I should have migrated by myself.

```
static final Migration MIGRATION_3_4 = new Migration(3, 4) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        // Create the new table
        database.execSQL(
                "CREATE TABLE users_new (userid TEXT, username TEXT, last_update INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(userid))");
// Copy the data
        database.execSQL(
                "INSERT INTO users_new (userid, username, last_update) SELECT userid, username, last_update FROM users");
// Remove the old table
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE users");
// Change the table name to the correct one
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE users_new RENAME TO users");
    }
};
```

Thanks to @Raghunandan